# why not using simple past when you can?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

This is a sentence from H. Potter book, p 154, the philosopher's Stone:

> Even Ron would tell anyone who'd listen about the time he'd almost hit a glider.

I understand that I can also put it in simple past tense without a change in the meaning:

> Even Ron would tell anyone who'd listen about the time he almost hit a glider.

I was wondering if I'm right.

Comment: I assume the repeated _who_ is an error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Rowling has backshifted the reported speech to the past perfect.  That is very natural when reporting an action that occurred in the past of a past tense narrative.

But there is practically no difference in using the past tense here.

Comment: OMG. so it's a reported speech. I always miss this part !

Comment: So syntactically speaking, I should definitely use past perfect.

Comment: Both are correct English.  Stylistically, perhaps past perfect is better.